# Keycloak of Jhipster 6.0.1 wouldn't start

Tags: docker, jhipster, keycloak

I am trying to start jhipster 6.0.1 docker keycloak but it wouldn't start at

I ran docker-compose -f keycloak.yml up and the image seems to be okay but it stopped at

```
    [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:10990/management
    [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:10990
```

[image]

and it hangs there with not further process.

there was no error what so ever.  it just wouldn't start.

below is the content in keycloak.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:6.0.1
    command:
      [
        '-b',
        '0.0.0.0',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING',
        '-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000',
      ]
    volumes:
      - ./realm-config:/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - DB_VENDOR=h2
    ports:
      - 9080:9080
      - 9443:9443
      - 10990:10990
```

Comment: can you post `keycloak.yml` to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment the last port 10990, it worked for me.

```
version: '3'
 services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:6.0.1

   command:
      [
        '-b',
       '0.0.0.0',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.dir=/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config',
        '-Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING',
        '-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=1000',
      ]

    volumes:
      - ./realm-config:/opt/jboss/keycloak/realm-config

    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_USER=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=admin
      - DB_VENDOR=h2

    ports:
      - 9080:9080
      - 9443:9443
      #- 10990:10990
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running docker using the toolbox?.

If this is the case, please notice that Docker won't be running using localhost, due is used a virtual box behind the scenes.

When you start Docker should appear a message, giving to you the port where docker is running:

[docker-run-show-server-address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEHtX.png)

In my case  192.168.99.100

Please go to 192.168.99.100:9080 and check if the Keycloak is running

In my case:

[keycloak-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teh7x.png)